# Datagrid no double click to edit columns

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using a WPF DataGrid in a simple Window to display some Data provided by a Model.

```xaml
<DataGrid x:Name="unitTable" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=IsChosen, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Chosen"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
         <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource boolToActive}}" Header="Active"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Everything worked perfectly fine with the model, but there was this problem where I had to double click the columns to edit the value of the checkboxes for example.

I came up with this solution:

```xaml
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="NoDoubleClick">
      <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
            </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And after I assigned the style to the Checkbox- and the first TextColumn it actually worked :)
After a while I realized, that the model doesn't get updated anymore when the Style "NoDoubleClick" was assigned to a column.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Set the UpdateSourceTrigger of your Binding to PropertyChanged.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @You're welcome, I'll add it as an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridColumns usually only update the bound data when the edited cells lose focus. To get around this and make it work with your Style, set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of your Binding to `PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Manfred Radlwimmer is right.

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

is needed to update the model.

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="unitTable" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=IsChosen, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Chosen"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
     <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource boolToActive}}" Header="Active"></DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, but we really don't need the same answer again, do we? (Especially since OP already confirmed that it worked)

Comment: why not? it is good to show in the code. or u can edit ur post with code. it is always easy to see with code. thats all.